# Is it wise to have two health insurance plans?

Tags: india, health-insurance, healthcare

I have not come across many articles discussing this topic, but I am guessing if it wise to have multiple health insurance plans. For example if there are two top health insurance plans. If I wanted to have 5 lakh cover, then is it wise to split them across two top health insurance plans or should I have single policy of 5L?